# Will I change the RPM of the front wheel of my bike (when lifting it off the ground) just by moving the handlebar back and forth?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I lift the front wheel of my bike off the ground and make it spin. I turn the handlebars right-left-right-left.
I feel the resistance of moving the handlebar back and forth. The faster the wheel spins the more resistance.

Will turning the handlebar back and forth change the RPM of the bike wheel, or would the wheel continue to rotate with the same RPM if there were no friction?
From my experience I think the RPM would not change, but I have not found a clear answer to this question.

Comment: Why do you think it might change?

Answer (score 1):

Turning the wheel produces a torque, but it is not in a direction that changes the speed of the wheel. The reaction torque may help you maintain your balance.